# extract *HQL* in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

Is there a way to extract the *HQL* from a Hibernate `Criteria` or `get` or `load` query? I have seen ways to extrac the SQL query from such objects but not HQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criteria goes directly to SQL, but there is no direct public api to get it programmatically in HQL.